# Why is torch.sum slower than torch.dot when accumulating elements?

Tags: python, pytorch

When I accumulate elements in a one-dimensional array `arr` with size `n`, I use `torch.sum` like below.

```py
import torch

n = 100000
arr = torch.randn(n)
res = torch.sum(arr)  # about 25.5μs
```

I also use `torch.dot` to accumulate elements of `arr` with the help of a helper array `helper_arr` of size `n` whose elements are all 1s, as shown in the following code.

```py
import torch

n = 100000
arr = torch.randn(n)

helper_arr = torch.ones(n)
res = torch.dot(arr, helper_arr)  # about 3.88μs
```

But I find that when `n` is 100000, `torch.sum` takes about 7 times longer than `torch.dot`. But when I increase `n` to 100000000, `torch.sum` takes less time than `torch.dot`. I don't know why this is happening, this question makes me very confused.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: not taking into account the time of initializing the tensors, torch.dot is always faster in my machine, which might be because dot method is optimized in pytorch.